# Catgory API that can be passed and word and returns the category it belongs to

Tags: php, objective-c, rest

Does anyone know of an API that can return a category for a given word, for example: pass it the word dog and return Category: animal?

Comment: "Dogs" are also a type of food.  Especially when served with chili.  "Dog" can also be a verb.  Should it return "Animal", "Food", or "To Pester, Annoy, or Harass"?  (It can also be an adjective)  In other words, your question is superbly broad and unanswerable.

Comment: Agree with @Dave_DeLong. Unless you can provide more context I'd say no, such an API doesn't exist :).

Comment: If you have a specific set of words and categories an answer can be formed, otherwise ... there is no answer I must agree.

Answer (score 0):

Your best best is to use a [Dictionary API](http://www.dictionaryapi.com/products/api-collegiate-dictionary.htm). If you look around, some might provide a specific category.